# DI logger object has unexpected minimum log level

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I was trying dependency injection by writing my own logger service for getting started purposes. I didn't want to implement log level logic so that I could log every level, so `IsEnabled` method returns true always. But when I call `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>` method returning logger object applies a minimum log level on the log commands, ie. `Log.LogTrace` and `Log.LogDebug` methods don't work whereas `Log.LogInformation` and `Log.LogWarning` methods work. Why does that happen?
Here is the code of this simple project:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sp = new ServiceCollection()
                        .AddLogging(builder =>
                        {
                            builder.AddProvider(new bLoggerProvider());
                        })
                        .BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

            logger.LogInformation("This works");
            logger.LogDebug("This doesn't work");

            var logger2 = sp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerProvider>().CreateLogger("Category Name");

            logger2.LogDebug("But this works");
        }
    }

    internal class bLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => new bLogger();

        public void Dispose() => throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

    internal class bLogger : ILogger
    {
        public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull => null;

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(formatter(state, exception));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two loggers are not the same.

#### First logger

The first logger is Microsoft built-in logger. When you resolve generic logger with type parameter `ILogger<Program>`, the service provider looks for matching registration. Executing `AddLogging()` adds such registration. See this open generic registration:

```cs
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

Full source code of `AddLogging()` can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L39).

An open generic registration means that a service provider will provide a generic instance of implementation type, when requested. So, in this case when you call `sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>()` the service provider will provide a singleton-lived instance of `Logger<Program>`. When we look at the source code of `Logger<T>` you can see that it's just a wrapper over `ILogger<T>` created from `ILoggerFactory` which is injected into it by DI:

```cs
public class Logger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Logger(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(factory);

        _logger = factory.CreateLogger(GetCategoryName());
    }
}
```

Source code of `Logger<T>` can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerT.cs#L29).

If you followed the path further and look at implementation of `ILoggerFactory` (which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggerFactory.cs#L139-L162)) you would see that more or less it just creates an instance of `Logger` while passing correct providers. You can track it down even further to reach the source of actual `Logger` (which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/Logger.cs#L27)) but at this point the conclusion should already be clear - first `ILogger<Program>` provided by a service provider is not an instance of `bLogger` and as such will not respect the log level you've set in your custom `bLogger`.

Since in your code there is no configuration regarding the minimum level of logging for the built-in logger, the information level is used. You can even see this being set explicitly in the source code of `AddLogging()`.

#### Second logger

The second logger however enables all logs since it's created directly from your custom logger provider. In your example, there is only one logger provider registered within DI container, so that's the one that will be resolved. Do notice that the logger created by your logger provider is not generic, so this should already be a hint that you are dealing with a different logger than the first one.

#### Solutions

Since in your question there is no really a problem to be found, rather a question for explanation, there won't be really a single solution here (except for the explanation above), because there are many approaches to resolve this. You essentially added a new logging provider, not replaced the logging system you've registered within DI by calling `AddLogging()`. You still can force your logger to be used when resolving generic loggers. In order to achieve that, you can repeat registration of the open generic logger:

```cs
var sp = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddProvider(new bLoggerProvider());
            })
            .AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(genericBLogger<>))
```

This is the new generic logger wrapper accepting type parameter:

```cs
internal class genericBLogger<T> : bLogger, ILogger<T>
{
}
```

Now, resolving any `ILogger<T>` from service provider e.g. `Program`:

```cs
var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

will get you an instance of `genericBLogger<Program>`, which will log **all** level log messages.